# Auth::attempt se rompe si añado una condicion mas

Tags: php, laravel

Hice mi propio login en Laravel usando Auth::attempt en vez de usar el de Laravel Ui, por alguna razón este Auth::atempt se rompe cuando meto un valor mas al If

Esto es lo que tengo en mi blade

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('postSignin') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">EMAIL: </label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">CLAVE: </label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">
                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        @if (\Session::has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        <ul>
            <li>{!! \Session::get('message') !!}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Login') }}
                                </button>

                                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('resetear') }}">
                                        {{ __('Olvido su clave?') }}
                                    </a>
                                @endif

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('index') }}">
                                        {{ __('Volver al inicio') }}
                                    </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Esto es lo que tengo en mi AdminModel

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AdminModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users'; //Obtiene la tabla
    public $timestamps = true; 
    protected $fillable = ['name, email, password, authorized, admin_creador']; //Estos son los datos que el Controller agarra
}
```

El problema es que por alguna razón, el Auth::attempt no agarra el campo authorized, lo que quiero es que si el campo authorized dice "yes", haga login, pero no lo agarra. Pero si agarra el de email y el de password bien y hace login, no se si debo editar algo en el vendor de Auth o algo así pero este me tiene confundido porque deberia funcionar pero no lo hace

Aqui esta el Controlador

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\StudentModel;
use App\AdminModel;
use Auth;
use Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Session;
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */

    public function postSignin(Request $request){ //Inicio de sesion
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'email|required',
            'password' => 'required|min:4'
        ]); //Valida los campos

        $email = $request['email'];
        $password = $request['password'];
        $authorized = "yes";

        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'authorized' => $authorized ])){
            return redirect()->route('home');
          }
}
}
```

Estructura de la tabla

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->enum('authorized', ['si', 'no']);
    $table->int('admin_creador');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta para agregar la estructura de tu tabla y un ejemplo de algún registro que no funciona.

Comment: La estructura de la tabla esta en el modal, toda esa informacion esta en la tabla de sql

Comment: Considera votar por arriba por mi respuesta :) Un gusto ayudarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero veo que en un tu `AdminModel` tienes un error aquí:

```
    protected $fillable = ['name, email, password, authorized, admin_creador'];
```

Deberías tener entre comillas todos los atributos deseados, de esta manera:

```
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'authorized', 'admin_creador'];
```

Además, desde mi punto de vista, es mejor práctica acceder a los datos del `$request` de la forma `$request->email`. Y aún más eficiente sería tener tu `form` con `input(name="user[email]")` e `input(name="user[password]")` más los campos que pertenezcan a `user`.

De esa forma te ahorras una líneas y usarías el método así `Auth::attempt($request->user)`

Asegúrate de que las variables extras que añadiste al `attempt()` existen en tu tabla de usuario en la base de datos, son condiciones para filtrar los registros de la tabla y busca en la misma.

También asegúrate de escribir un `else` en caso de que no se autentique `Auth` como, por ejemplo, `redirect()->back()->withErrors(["email" => "No existe ese email"])`